# sql server full text search not returning correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have full text catalogue defined on below table on all_metadata row:

```
ft_id   record_id   am_changestamp  all_metadata          
21  42  2012-09-11 17:07:25.553  Photos Project 1234 5678 |Mockups|pictures|Abbot| testing Revenue migration testing Getty Images Abbot g  test.txt                                                        

22  43  2012-09-11 17:11:06.147  Photos Project 1234 5678 |Mockups|pictures|Abbot| testing Revenue migration testing Getty Images Abbot g  test1.txt
```

The SQL I am running is:

```
select f0.record_id from ft_all_metadata as f0, 
containstable(ft_all_metadata, all_metadata, N'Images') as kt where f0.ft_id = kt.[key]
```

The SQL returns the first row but not the second!!!! I am really baffled!

I have tried re-creating and re-building the full-text catalogue with no luck.

Your help is appreciated,
Bruce

Comment: The query works fine for me using a full-text index. Can you post your SQL for creating the full-text catalog or index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had relied on SQL Server Manager GUI to do this and must have done something incorrectly.

So decided to do this through commands and this works now:

exec sp_fulltext_catalog 'Catalogu_Name', 'create'

exec sp_fulltext_table 'table_name', 'create', 'Catalogu_Name', 'table_index_name'

exec sp_fulltext_column 'table_name', 'column_name', 'add'

exec sp_fulltext_table 'table_name', 'activate'

exec sp_fulltext_catalog 'Catalogu_Name', 'start_full'

I created a separate index for table_index_name on the primary key.